# In C++ is it a good practice to use 'this'?

Tags: c++, coding-style

I was wondering if it was a good practice to use 'this' in C++. At first I thought I should be because that way you make obvious that the thing you are referring is a member of the current class but sometimes you end with code like:

```
Document::Document(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    this->file = 0;
    this->layout = new QGridLayout(this);
    this->layout->setSpacing(2);
    this->layout->setMargin(0);
    this->setLayout(this.layout);
    this->textArea = new QTextEdit(this);
    this->textArea->setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit::NoWrap);
    this->textArea->setAcceptDrops(true);
    this->textArea->setAcceptRichText(true);
    this->textArea->setUndoRedoEnabled(true);
    this->textArea->setFont(QFont("Mono" , 11));
    this->layout->addWidget(this->textArea);
    this->textArea->show();
    this->textArea->setFocus();
}
```

I thing this would look a lot better without all the 'this' specially when it  is used like `this->layout->addWidget(this.textArea);`. And I think the code should use the same style in most cases to make it easier to be read so, should I use 'this' just when it is necessary or is it a good practice to use it to make clear that you are referencing a member of the same class.

Comment: I've seen it used in a few cases if variables being passed in to the function have the same name as member variables. This is common in constructors. Then you can say `this->myVal = myVal` and it does the right thing. Otherwise I typically don't like it.

Comment: The real problem with this code is not the use of `this`, but the memory leaks. There are too many _actual_ problems with code (in general, as well as in this case) to worry about such minor points.

Comment: @StilesCrisis But if you're writing the function yourself, you're also choosing the name of the argument, so you can easily change it into something that doesn't require the `this->`. That's what I do.

Comment: @MrLister Because 'this' is a pointer in C++ `this.textArea` would give an error. It should be `this->textArea` or `*this.textArea` to acces the object pointed by 'this' and not the pointer itself.

Comment: @MrLister: Hmm, on a second reading of the code I realised that there isn't actually enough information to know for sure, so I retract my previous statement.

Comment: @MrLister Yeah sorry but it doesn't let me correct just 2 characters :(

Comment: @Mankarse It doesn't have any leaks, at least at this point. They are pointers because I need to pass them to other methods and when I'm going to modify an object in a method I prefer pointers over references because it is obvious to the programmer using the function that the object passed might be modified.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no single answer to this. It depends on the context, and it depends on who you ask.

Some people use `this` all the time. Some never use it. Some instead rename all member variables with a special prefix (`mFile` instead of `file`).

I prefer to only use the `this` prefix when it's necessary to avoid ambiguity.

In well written code, it is usually obvious whether you're referring to a local or a member variable, and so `this` doesn't really do much. But sometimes it can be hard for the reader to determine if a variable is a class member or not. Then `this` is a good way to clarify.

Comment: Perhaps, it is better to prefix your member variables with something, like a single underscore or an m, or m_, etc if just that be the reason?

Comment: I don't usually use a "member prefix", because it seems pointless. We already *have* a standard prefix in the form of `this->`, and I can (and do) use it whenever necessary. When it's not necessary. I don't want to clutter my code up with some faux hungarian notation

Comment: Since this as well is a matter of preference & choice more than that of synatactial correctness I am going to say fair enough if thats your preference :)

Answer (score 9):

If using `this` makes it easier to read (easier to understand, that is) then the extra typing is well worth the effort.

In a complex program every line of code will be written once but read many times (and by different programmers), so it's a good investment.

One of the most readable languages I know, Python, forces you to write `self.x` (the equivalent of `this->x` of C++) every single time and that is not an issue at all. The problem with it is that in Python when you write `slef.x` instead of `self.x` the error is caught at **runtime**, but this is a different unrelated issue...

Answer (score 3):

It makes no difference to the compiler(in your example).
Its a matter of preference of users, Some find it more intutive, while some find it unrequired extra typing.
So just Use it if the coding guidelines you use say you should.

Note that certain cases you do need to use `this` because there is no other way to go about it but that is not your question as I see it.

Comment: And the reason for downvote is...? What do you disagree with or what do you think is incorrect?

Comment: OP knows it makes no difference to the compiler, and it would seem that they have no style guidelines to follow.

Comment: @Marcin: How did you reach the sweeping conclusion of *"it would seem that they have no style guidelines to follow"*? Since, this is a mere matter of preference the answer to OPs q is to use what the coding guidlenes say or choose what you are asked to do.There is no correct answer in this case.

Comment: My conclusion is neither sweeping nor odd. If you have nothing useful to contribute, you are not required to post an answer.

Comment: @Marcin: Thanks for your comments which amount to nothing else but utter nonesense.

Comment: Really? How do you figure? Which parts did you not understand? Do you believe you have to answer every C++ question?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I don't like using `this`.
But I think this is a personal preference thing. As long as your consistent it should not matter.

Note: I also make sure that I compile with -WShadow -WError

Comment: What are those arguments for?

Comment: @Topo: shadowing occurs when a variable in an inner scope has the same name than a variable in an outer scope. If I write a class with an attribute `x` and a method of this class has an argument `x`, then in this method the argument *shadows* the attribute. `-Wshadow` make the compiler warns about it, `-Werror` turns the warning into an error, to make sure you do not let it slip by.

Comment: +1 just because there's been too much downvoting on personal preferences for other answers and because this is my personal preference. I like `this->` to stick out like the sore thumb that it is, only using `this->` as a clue that "trickiness lies here" (e.g. two-phase name lookup).

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion is not common to use "this" for members. IMHO it looks quite messy. I prefer using "m_" prefix for all members, so it's clear what is member and what is local variable. Anyway there are more important good practice see e.g More Effective C++ written by Scott Meyers.

Comment: Please consider write reason why my answer is down voted, to avoid future wrong answers. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I downvoted this because it adds no information about good practices, and you recommend a book because of information it holds on unspecified topics.

Answer (score 0):

I generally prefer code which uses `this` for all members.

In your example it looks redundant because you don't refer to any local variables. However, in code that uses a mixture of local and instance (or even class) variables, it's much nicer to know exactly where to look.